# How to treat relative path as full URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, path

I am trying to make a URL shortener app like bit.ly with Django. It works when the {var} leads to absolute URL but I cannot figure out how to redirect links without prefixes like "http//:www.".

So far I tried `HttpResponseRedirect(link)`, `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(link)` and `redirect(link)`

Example:

`link = "https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/"` => works as expected

`link = "postgresql.org/docs/current/"` => redirects to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/{var}/postgresql.org/docs/current/"

In the browser search tab both links redirect as expected so how to treat something like this `"postgresql.org/docs/current/"` as a full URL? I am using a function not a class-based view.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put some check like this in code before redirect:

```
if not link.startswith('http//:www.'):
   link = 'http//:www.' + link
```